VBDepend API is available?
I have a requirement to analyze and get technical dept details for the VB6 project. I came to know about VBDepend. And I downloaded the evaluation pack and created the report using Visual VB depend tool. But I need to get those metrics using API(Programmatically) is any API available in VBDepend like Ndepend API. I couldn't find any documentation in Code gear.
I need documentation or sample project reference to VB6 project metrics using VBDepend api

It has a command line, maybe that can be used programmatically. http://www.vbdepend.com/VBDependConsole

Your best bet is to ask the developers of that tool.
